# Linux Joomla Can't write to file with 755 permission

Tags: linux, joomla

Hello I am trying to setup Joomla.  When I try to change some settings through the Global Settings Manager, and then save, I keep getting and error saying I can't write to that file.

I have tried playing around with the settings and file permissions even changing them to 755, and it still won't let me write to the file.

I have the owner set to 'root.root' and am running Fedora 18.

I have it installed on localhost, and not through FTP.

Why can't I write to these files (like configuration.php), is there something I am missing?

Joomla does not tell me what file I am trying to write to, but I assume if I'm editing Global Settings it attempts to write to configuration.php.

here is the output of ls -l /var/www/html/joomla

```
total 116
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache 17816 Nov  6 15:18 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache  4300 Nov  6 15:18 README.txt
drwxr-xr-x. 10 apache apache  4096 Nov  6 15:18 administrator
drwxr-xr-x.  2 apache apache  4096 Nov  6 15:18 bin
drwxr-xr-x.  2 apache apache  4096 Nov  6 15:18 cache
drwxr-xr-x.  2 apache apache  4096 Nov  6 15:18 cli
drwxr-xr-x. 17 apache apache  4096 Nov  6 15:18 components
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache  2018 Dec  6 05:56 configuration.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache  3118 Nov  6 15:18 htaccess.txt
drwxr-xr-x.  5 apache apache  4096 Nov  6 15:18 images
drwxr-xr-x.  2 apache apache  4096 Nov  6 15:18 includes
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache  1011 Nov  6 15:18 index.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache  1909 Nov  6 15:20 joomla.xml
drwxr-xr-x.  4 apache apache  4096 Nov  6 15:18 language
drwxr-xr-x.  4 apache apache  4096 Nov  6 15:18 layouts
drwxr-xr-x. 12 apache apache  4096 Nov  6 15:18 libraries
drwxr-xr-x.  2 apache apache  4096 Dec  6 04:51 logs
drwxr-xr-x. 18 apache apache  4096 Nov  6 15:18 media
drwxr-xr-x. 28 apache apache  4096 Nov  6 15:18 modules
drwxr-xr-x. 14 apache apache  4096 Nov  6 15:18 plugins
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache   901 Nov  6 15:18 robots.txt.dist
drwxr-xr-x.  5 apache apache  4096 Dec  6 04:39 templates
drwsr-xr-x.  2 apache apache  4096 Dec  6 04:44 tmp
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache  1715 Nov  6 15:18 web.config.txt
```

And output of `ls -ld joomla/`

```
drwxr-xr-x. 18 apache apache 4096 Dec  6 05:57 joomla/
```

Also, running the command `tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log` I get this

```
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/www/html/joomla/configuration.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/joomla/libraries/joomla/filesystem/file.php on line 422, referer: http://localhost/administrator/index.php?option=com_config
```

Answer (score 2):

After digging a bit deeper into the problem. I discovered that SELinux was blocking r/w access to httpd. This could be seen when running

```
ls -aLZ joomla
```

By running the command you would see that all files would show up to be

```
httpd_sys_content_t
```

When they really should be

```
httpd_sys_rw_content_t
```

Running a simple

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/html/joomla/
```

AND VOILA! Problem Solved.

Thank you everyone for the help, and I hope someone else can benefit from this in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the webserver?

As the permission must get reflected.